# What do you call someone who believes strongly in justice, and will do anything to uphold it?

Tags: adjectives

Any when I say justice, I mean the higher principle of justice, not just the physical law, but someone who believes in the higher meaning of justice, almost a nobility....but will fight to uphold it.

Comment: Does [Social justice warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_justice_warrior) work for you?

Comment: The 9 people who make up the Supreme Court of the United States are known as ... *Justices*. But there are other words; the acronym *SJW* stands for *Social Justice Warrior*.

Comment: The problem is that people have a different idea of what "justice" is. See [vigalante](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vigilante).

Comment: Exactly. Without knowing what that person believes the 'higher meaning' of justice to be and what they are prepared to do to uphold it, it is impossible to label them.

Comment: I've seen this quality called *an obsessive sense of justice.*  For a noun, the proposed *crusader* sounds good.

Answer (score 4):

[**Crusader**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crusader)

> A person who campaigns vigorously for political, social, or religious change; a campaigner

This allows you to apply the term to passionate individual in any field or with any goal. It can also lend a hint of righteousness due to the term originating from the Holy Crusades starting in the 11th century.

I am always reminded of [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Caped_Crusader), who is also known as "The Caped Crusader".

Answer (score 1):

They are an **untouchable**.

> The Untouchables were a group of nine U.S. federal law-enforcement agents led by Eliot Ness, who, from 1929 to 1931, worked to end Al Capone's illegal activities by aggressively enforcing Prohibition laws against Capone and his organization. In their conduct, they became legendary for being fearless and incorruptible, earning the nickname "The Untouchables".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untouchables_(law_enforcement)

Answer (score -2):

A ***superhero*** - A person with extraordinary heroic (brave, courageous, noble) attributes (OED).

> 1899   Daily Mail 29 Sept. 4/4   M. Clémenceau suddenly burst out with, ‘*All the world knows that Colonel Picquart is a hero, but..if Colonel Picquart is a hero, Mathieu Dreyfus is a super-hero*.’(OED)
>
> 1917   ‘Contact’ Airman's Outings 211   *The super-heroes of the war*. (OED).

Comment: Clearly a strong contender, but devalued and trivialised for having become associated with fantasy characters.

Answer (score -3):

Humanitarian is the accepted term, or egalitarian..

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Being a humanitarian is orthagonal to being an egalitarian.